# saving Image path im database

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, xaml, uri

I've got a SQLite database (sqlite-net-pcl) in my C# Maui project and want to save a URI as a string to a jpg resource inside my project. Problem is, it's just not working. I even created a converter to get it showing me the picture, but no chance.

This is the code in XAML.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imagePathConverter}}" WidthRequest="66" />
```

That's the converter it's refering to.

```
    public class ImagePathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var imagePath = (string)value;
            return ImageSource.FromResource(imagePath);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Some variants of the strings I saved but didn't showed any results:

"~/Resources/Images/Thumb/adv1.jpg"
"./Resources/Images/Thumb/adv1.jpg"
"/MyAssembly;/Images/Thumb/adv1.jpg"
"resource://MyAssembly.Images.Thumb.adv1.jpg"
$"{assemblyName}.Images.Thumb.adv1.jpg"

...and many many other variations. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Tried to save different variants of strings, but it's not showing the picture in XAML. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: are your images copied to resources folder upon build in executable path ?

Comment: Yes, it's declared as resource during build process.

Comment: did you try just "Resources/Images/.."

Comment: Yes, I did. And couple other variations. But somehow not the right one.